# laravel shows me this error The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD, PUT, DELETE

Tags: laravel

laravel show me this error when i submit  in the form of create 
"The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD, PUT, DELETE. "
I'm working on one page parent.blade .php the forms appear in the same page 
routes :

```
Route::get('parents', 'ParentController@index'); 
Route::get('parents/create', 'ParentController@create'); 
Route::post('parents', 'ParentController@store'); 
Route::get('parents/{id}/edit', 'ParentController@edit'); 
Route::put('parents/{id}', 'ParentController@update'); 
Route::delete('parents/{id}', 'ParentController@destroy');
```

And these are controller methods:

```
public function create()
{
    return view('admin.parent');
}

/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */

public function store(Request $request)
{
    $parent = new Parent();
     $parent->nom = $request->input('nom');
     $parent->nom = $request->input('prenom');
     $parent->nom = $request->input('adresse');
     $parent->nom = $request->input('num-tel');
     $parent->nom = $request->input('email');
     $parent->nom = $request->input('login');
     $parent->nom = $request->input('password');
     $parent->save();
     return view('admin.parent');    
}
```

Comment: Add your view please.

Comment: To make sure everything is up to date, do:
php artisan route:clear

Answer (score 1):

try

```
Route::resource('parents','ParentController')
```

blade

### store

```
     <form method="POST" action="{{route('parents.store')}}">
     {{ csrf_field() }}
     ...
     </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to change the order of routes in web.php

```
 Route::get('parents', 'ParentController@index');
 Route::post('parents', 'ParentController@store')->name('parents.store');  
 Route::get('parents/create', 'ParentController@create'); 
 Route::get('parents/{id}/edit', 'ParentController@edit'); 
 Route::put('parents/{id}', 'ParentController@update'); 
 Route::delete('parents/{id}', 'ParentController@destroy');
```

In your view

```
<form method="POST" action="{{route('parents.store')}}">
 {{ csrf_field() }}

 </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Route::post('parents', 'ParentController@store');
```

Comment: add this code in your html form <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">

Answer (score 0):

I also had this

```
Route::get('/student/store', [StudentController::class, 'store'])->name('student.store');
```

and I changed it to

```
Route::post('/student/store', [StudentController::class, 'store'])->name('student.store');
```

you see I had `get`, I changed it to `post`.

Answer (score 0):

So you need to understand the cycle of Laravel routes.

```
Route::post('/any-url', 'CONTROLLER@functionToCAll')
```

this means that on the HTML side you can use method="POST" in the Post Section to trigger

```
<form method="POST" action="{{route('YourRouteName')}}">
 {{ csrf_field() }}

 </form>
```

if you want to trigger the delete or update function of the controller
you had to include

1. {{ method_field('PATCH') }}  -> for UPDATE
2. {{ method_field('DELETE')}}  -> For Delete

and the best way to use these is after  tag

```
<form method="POST" action="{{route('YourRouteName')}}">
    {{ method_field('PATCH') }}
```

Note: you can also use Route::Any for efficiency

```
Route:any(['POST','GET','PUT'], 'CONTROLLR@Function');
```